# Squash and merge VS squash and rebase

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

What is the difference between 'Squash and Merge' which is one of the option for Pull request merging and 'Squash and Rebase' which can be done by `git rebase -i` option?

Why people recommend 'Squash and Rebase' while 'Squash and Merge' exists?

I'm trying to use the git workflow. Previously I used rebase to merge commits from the feature branch into the develop branch. This makes the develop branch neat and the merged feature branch can be deleted.

However, there was a problem that the develop branch became too long if there were too many commits in the feature branch. So I try to squash commits while merging feature branches.

Then I found that git hub provides 'Squash and Merge' but also some people recommend 'Squash and Rebase'.

I've tried both and it makes no difference other than the other commit messages where the 'Squash and Rebase' commit has all the commit messages, while the 'Squash and Merge' has none.

Comment: Can you link to an example of someone recommending "Squash and Rebase"? It would help confirm what process they're referring to, and also make the question a bit less opinion-based.

Comment: @IMSoP I added more explanations that I tried.

Comment: There's no such thing as "squash and rebase". GitHub have three options: "merge", "rebase and merge", and "squash and merge". There's no "squash and rebase" here. I'm afraid you're getting a lot of mash-up answers as people are guessing what you mean.

Comment: As torek says, it's still not really clear what you're referring to as "Squash and Rebase", and where you've seen it offered or recommended. Meanwhile, you say "... it makes no difference other than [a difference]" - so doesn't that answer your own question about the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to avoid having a dirty tree, as if you don't rebase before merging with main branch. And you have multiples branches, it will quickly look something like this : [image: spaghetti tree]
You will agree with me that it is very hard to see what's going on.
With rebase before merging, it will look way cleanier and will be way more easy to understand : [image: Not spaghetti tree]

Comment: your example is more about why squashing

Comment: Not really but yeah, I've done the error to make two commits for the branch feature/merge, but it doesn't change that for the 3 other branches, there is a a single commit per branch

Comment: @Ôrel but anyways, your answer is still better ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not pure cosmetics.
Doing rebase allow to have the conflict resolved into the commit itself, whereas without rebasing, the merge commit can contain some diff due to the conflict.

Without rebasing you can track from where the branch has started and can allow to track the time to deliver or other things.
NB: This is not 'Squash and Merge' but `Rebase and Merge`

With visual it is easier:

Allow merge commits
Add all commits from the head branch to the base branch with a merge commit.

Combine all commits from the head branch into a single commit in the base branch.

Allow

merge commits

```
2021-09-02 17:05 +0200 John doe     M─│─┐ Merge branch 'bug51' into 'release'
2021-09-02 16:51 +0200 John doe     │ │ o Fix stupid bug
2021-09-02 16:42 +0200 John doe     │ │ o Try to fix
2021-09-02 15:50 +0200 John doe     M─│─│─┐ Merge branch 'featcool' into 'release'
2021-08-20 12:05 +0200 John doe     │ │ │ o Add a new cool feature
2021-08-20 10:47 +0200 John doe     │ │ │ o WIP cool feature
2021-09-02 15:22 +0200 John doe     M─│─│─┤ Merge branch 'feat2' into 'release'
2021-09-02 14:56 +0200 John doe     │ │ │ o chore: feat2
2021-09-02 10:16 +0200 John doe     M─│─│─│─┐ Merge branch 'feat1' into 'release'
2021-08-31 18:28 +0200 John doe     │ │ │ │ o  feature so nice
```

rebase merging

```
2021-09-02 16:51 +0200 John doe      o Fix stupid bug
2021-09-02 16:42 +0200 John doe      o Try to fix
2021-08-20 12:05 +0200 John doe      o Add a new cool feature
2021-08-20 10:47 +0200 John doe      o WIP cool feature
2021-09-02 14:56 +0200 John doe      o chore: feat2
2021-08-31 18:28 +0200 John doe      o feature so nice
```

Squash merging

```
2021-09-02 16:51 +0200 John doe      o Fix stupid bug
2021-08-20 12:05 +0200 John doe      o Add a new cool feature
2021-09-02 14:56 +0200 John doe      o chore: feat2
2021-08-31 18:28 +0200 John doe      o feature so nice
```

Comment: I believe the last option, which you call "squash rebase merge (fast-forward)" is what the command `git merge --squash` does, what I have always seen referred to as a "squash merge", and what [Github offers in the UI as "Squash and Merge"](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/about-pull-request-merges). I'm not sure which of the other two the OP is asking about.

Comment: `git merge` when possible resolve the merge as a fast-forward (only update the branch pointer to match the merged branch; do not create  a merge commit) `-ff` by default.
See `--ff, --no-ff, --ff-only` params, nothing relative to squash

Comment: I specifically mentioned the "--squash" flag, so what happens by default isn't really relevant. I also linked to the Github help page, which is more relevant to the question, and clearly matches your third diagram, not either of the other two.

Comment: Third one can be done with `git merge --squash`, using a merge request you can have the merge commit introduced.
For the second one can be done by squashing by hand with `git rebase -i` or y using `git merge --squash`, `git commit` and a git `merge -no-ff`
A classic is a next version branch where you merge with squash all features, and do a final real merge.

I prefer gitlab for this, where you can force every merge to do a merge request, and configure squash in another part. This can do the second one or the first one.

Comment: Maybe your familiarity with Gitlab is what is confusing things - I don't know what options it offers. But to repeat myself again: Github's "Squash and merge" option corresponds to your third diagram; it never creates a merge commit.

Comment: Sorry, the pblm is ` 'Squash and Rebase' while 'Squash and Merge'` this is not squash and merge on github but 'Rebase and merge' I update my answer